# Target Coordinates To Screen Coordinates - Vuforia

Tags: vuforia

I just want to get the 2dscreen coords of a target calculated from the info in the returned pose in iOS.

Would someone take pity and please provide me with an answer as I have virtually finished the app I was working on and that is the last piece I need.  I looked at the documentation but I don't understand matrix math.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to get an approximation of the X & y 2D position on the screen which is all I needed, so for those who are struggling like me and can't find the correct way to do it here is my odd way of doing it.

Using the iOS sample app as a base; I added the following line inside the AppController::getImageTargetResult function.

```
vuMatrix44FGetPoseRot (modelViewMatrix, &translation, &axis, &angle);
```

The translation is a VuVector3F and receives the 3D position where translation.data [0] has the Y, the translation.data [1] recieves the X, and translation.data [2] recieves the Z.  The range of these values go from -1.0 to +1.0.

In the rendering section in VuforiaViewController.swift I normalize these values

```
  // First I get the screen dimensions.

  let screenWidth  = Float (UIScreen.main.bounds.width)

  let screenHeight = Float (UIScreen.main.bounds.height)


  // Then I normalize the z value to convert it to a range of 0.0 to 1.0

  let z_Position = (UserDefaults.standard.float (forKey: "model_Position_Z") + 1.0) / 2.0

  // I create a depth factor variable for both x and y that I use to scale the calculated screen position

  // so that it moves less when further away and more when it is closer.  I got the 0.070 and 0.014 from

  // experimentation and do not understand them.

  let x_depth: Float = (screenWidth  * 0.070) * z_Position

  let y_depth: Float = (screenHeight * 0.014) * z_Position

  // Then I normalize the x & y values and multiplied them with the depth variables

  let x_Position = ((UserDefaults.standard.float (forKey: "model_Position_X") * x_depth) + 1.0) / 2.0

  let y_Position = ((UserDefaults.standard.float (forKey: "model_Position_Y") * y_depth) + 1.0) / 2.0
 
  // And finally I multiplied them by the screen width to get the answer

  let screen_x = CGFloat (x_Position * screenWidth)

  let screen_y = CGFloat (y_Position * screenHeight)
```

I understand that this is not the correct way of doing it, but it was fine for what I needed and it allowed me to finish my project.

Comment: so is this a solution? Or are you still looking for an answer to your question? Is this additional information to be added to the question?

Comment: It is a poor workaround for an approximation that did satisfy my needs, but it would be good to keep it open for a bit longer in case someone was kind enough to answer it correctly for others that might need a precise answer.  If not, then I could ask the question again another time.